# Can't see Add Controller/Add View in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I know there are already many threads on stackoverflow about this problem but they are all old and all the solutions work only for Visual Studio 2012/13. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I have the same problem. 
I'm learning ASP.NET from a book and I've installed everything they have, and created the project exactly as they have but still can't see the 'Add Controller/Add View' options.
I've tried altering my ProjectGuids and that stuff but it is all incompatible since every solution I've found online is regarding older versions of Visual Studio.
Any ideas?

Comment: What edition of VS 2015 do you use?

Comment: Community, same as in the book

Comment: Are you creating an `ASP.NET 4.6` project or `ASP.NET 5`?

Comment: It says 'ASP.NET Framework 4.5.2'

Comment: The max option if 4.6.1. 
EDIT: Just checked, the book uses 4.5